# sql запрос в python поиск строки по слову

Tags: python, sql

Как сделать поиск строк из таблицы по одному введеному слову, если в ячейке строка
знаю что надо ставить проценты вокруг вопроса, но он на них ругается

```
import sqlite3 as sq

def sql_start():
    global base, cur
    base = sq.connect('avtozapchasti.db')
    cur = base.cursor()
    if base:
        print('data ok')

sql_start()

data = input('Введите имя')

row = """Select name, adress, contact, site From poisk where search LIKE ?"""
rom =cur.execute(row, (data,))
for ret in rom:
    print(ret)
```

Comment: row = f"Select name, adress, contact, site From poisk where search LIKE '%{data}%'" ну и execute без data

Comment: ну ты кросавчеГ, спасибо

Comment: Как показал Виктор, лучше не использовать, потому что возникает уязвимость SQL инъекции